# How do you set subtypes for Collector to create multiple choice dropdowns

Tags: arcgis-10.2, domains, arcgis-collector, subtype

I am trying to set up a Collector map for a wetland area to follow the format the [Georgia Adopt-A-Wetland Visual Survey form](http://www.georgiaadoptastream.com/Manuals_etc/MonitoringForms/VisualAllForms.pdf?4) has. I have been following the Collector setup guide [here](http://www.esri.com/esri-news/arcuser/summer-2013/create-your-own-collector-map), but I am having trouble creating the subtypes and knowing what codes to use for the survey format.

For example, I want there to be a dropdown for Weather Conditions, and the options would be: Clear, Cloudy, Rain, & Rain within the last 24 to 48 hours. I understand that this would not really be a location point as far as feature classes go, but it would be a start.

The rest of the domain and subtypes would continue to follow the Visual Survey form.

Comment: The .pdf you link to has a number of forms. Would you like the collector app to collect one point for multiple forms or one point per form? If you set up the underlying feature classes with the correct domains and subtypes the collector app should pick up on this. Weather observations could be per feature class or in a separate related table, but I'm not sure the collector app can handle related features.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do. Domains and subtypes apply to attributes of features. So you'd need a point feature, and it would have an attribute WeatherCond, and that attribute would have a Domain of valid values which are [your list]. Subtypes are [something different](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/96153/), for when you want two different possible domains for a particular attribute based on the value of another attribute.

Comment: Basically what I want to do is have a drop down menu in Collector titled: Water Source. then have 5 options to choose in the drop down as: Precipitation, Groundwater, Stream/river/lake, Coastal, & Other. The tutorial available for creating a Collector Map is not really helping. I don't know if it's because I'm using Arcmap 10.2.2 and the tutorial was made for an earlier version that is not matching up now, because it's not working the way they're telling me to set it up as.

Comment: As suggested by Chris W: 1. Create point feature class in FGDB. 2. Create coded domain - long-integer, listing all of 5 options 'e.eg. 0- Precipitation. 3. Create field TYPE (long integer). 4. In arccatalog assign domain to this field. After sharing this feature as service user will deal with domain. period

Comment: Your comment describes another attribute with its own domain, separate from the one in your question, and they are unrelated. I read through the tutorial and don't see anything there that shouldn't work beyond so far you don't have anything that would require subtypes. Admittedly the tutorial doesn't provide a clear graphic of the overall relationships. Think of each question in your form as an attribute field and each group of check boxes (which answer one question) as the domain. You only need a subtype if for example two of the odor choices can only apply to one source choice.